# Create a continuous heatmap

Tags: python

Most heatmap tutorials look at discrete data, where each cell has a well-defined boundary and a single value. How do you create a heatmap of continuous data, where individual points may be very close together without actually being identical?

Example: I have a set of 1000 map coordinates, all in the range (-8192, -8192) to (8192, 8192). They might look like this:

```
745.2218627929688,808.1373901367188
741.4943237304688,775.325927734375
757.3713989257812,806.7517700195312
-300.1320495605469,1425.9727783203125
-1845.8055419921875,2091.180419921875
-289.85308837890625,1429.4222412109375
-306.8935241699219,1434.9525146484375
-287.78253173828125,1439.9078369140625
```

The locations will tend to be clustered, and the clusters are the most interesting, but outliers are still of some value. What I'd like would be to show colours on an image that indicate this density.

It's highly likely that all I need is the right term to search for, but "heatmap" keeps finding discrete data tutorials only :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes, your requirements are too specific or too unusual, and you have to just write your own. By looking at various existing options - including those posted by WBM and tkarahan - thank you both! - I was able to craft my own heatmap code, based on a distance-squared linear dropoff and calculations of actual distance, regardless of the quantization that results from pixel calculations. To anyone else who's trying to make a heatmap, chances are you can use imshow, which is very close to what I was looking for; otherwise, build your own to match your precise requirements. Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

What about `imshow`? Check these [different interpolation methods](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/images_contours_and_fields/interpolation_methods.html#sphx-glr-gallery-images-contours-and-fields-interpolation-methods-py) which will allow you to define the "discreteness".

Example with quadric interpolation:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

harvest = np.array([[0.8, 2.4, 2.5, 3.9, 0.0, 4.0, 0.0],
                    [2.4, 0.0, 4.0, 1.0, 2.7, 0.0, 0.0],
                    [1.1, 2.4, 0.8, 4.3, 1.9, 4.4, 0.0],
                    [0.6, 0.0, 0.3, 0.0, 3.1, 0.0, 0.0],
                    [0.7, 1.7, 0.6, 2.6, 2.2, 6.2, 0.0],
                    [1.3, 1.2, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 3.2, 5.1],
                    [0.1, 2.0, 0.0, 1.4, 0.0, 1.9, 6.3]])


fig, ax = plt.subplots()
im = ax.imshow(harvest,interpolation="quadric")
```

Output image:

[image]

Comment: Played around with this, but it still can't handle arbitrarily-fine data. See self-answer. I appreciate the help though! Unfortunately the best I can do is give you an upvote.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Plotly density hetmap.

```
import plotly.express as px
import pandas as pd

data = [
    [745.2218627929688,808.1373901367188],
    [741.4943237304688,775.325927734375],
    [757.3713989257812,806.7517700195312],
    [-300.1320495605469,1425.9727783203125],
    [-1845.8055419921875,2091.180419921875],
    [-289.85308837890625,1429.4222412109375],
    [-306.8935241699219,1434.9525146484375],
    [-287.78253173828125,1439.9078369140625],
]

df = pd.DataFrame(data=data, columns=['latitude', 'longitude'])
df['magnitude'] = df.groupby(['latitude', 'longitude']).size().reset_index(drop=True)
fig = px.density_mapbox(df, lat='latitude', lon='longitude', z='magnitude', radius=10,
                        center=dict(lat=0, lon=180), zoom=0,
                        mapbox_style="stamen-terrain")
fig.show()
```

https://plotly.com/python/mapbox-density-heatmaps/

Comment: It is for real map locations of course, and you need more data.

Comment: Does it make a difference that I'm not using an actual map of Planet Earth? This is some game data that I'm using, so the map I'm working on is the game's map. I'll test out your code as soon as I can, but am currently building CPython 3.11 since 3.10 didn't work for this.

Comment: It takes coordinates of real places.

Comment: Okay, not what I'm looking for then, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I have a very similar task at hand as the initial post by rosuav, that is: plotting the *density of a 2D dataset* as heatmap.

So what I need is a two-dimensional histogram, and the bar height (of a standard 1D histogram) becomes the color in the 2D histogram, i. e. the heatmap.

And exactly this exists: matplotlib's **hist2d()**, see [here](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.hist2d.html).

The dataset shown above is not very suited to prove the point, so I created my own:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.colors as mcolors

n = 10000    
df = pd.DataFrame({'x': np.random.randn(n), 'y': np.random.randn(n)})

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
gamma = 0.5

plt.hist2d(df['x'], df['y'], bins=100, norm=mcolors.PowerNorm(gamma))

plt.title("Normal distributed 2D data")
plt.show()
```

[image]

Of course, hist2d offers many more parameters to customize the output.